# Reformatting to have method parameters in a new line

Tags: objective-c, coding-style, appcode

There are so many settings in the preferences for Code->Style->Objective-C. I'm looking for the right one to reformat this line of code

```
SCPropertyDefinition *test = [SCPropertyDefinition definitionWithName:@"created_at" title:@"Tweeted At" type:SCPropertyTypeLabel];
```

to this format

```
SCPropertyDefinition *test = [SCPropertyDefinition definitionWithName:@"created_at" 
                                                                title:@"Tweeted At" 
                                                                 type:SCPropertyTypeLabel];
```

(the point is to have the colons indention matching)

I guess the it should be in the Wrapping and Braces Tab, but I havn't found the right setting yet.
Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is `Wrapping and Braces | Method call arguments` set to `Chop down if long` with enabled `Align by colon`. Note that there are separate settings for `Method parameters`.

Comment: It seems like this option was removed from AppCode 2. Or moved, but I can't find it. I wish there was a hotkey to toggle a line between the two formatting forms.

Comment: No it's still there. You should go to settings->Code Style->Obj-C look for "Method parameters" and change "Do not wrap" to "Wrap always" or "Chop down if long"

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. I can't find any reference to Chop Down if Long in Appcode 3.3. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like as of App Code 2017.1 (perhaps earlier too) the align by colon option is not available in Swift. You can still tell App Code to chop a long argument/parameter list:

[image: How to find the chop long line dialog]

Answer (score 1):

*(1000 years later, updated to Xcode 15)*

##### Editor > Structure > Format to Multiple Lines:

From

```
ManyParamInit(param1: String, param2: String, param3: String)
```

To:

```
ManyParamInit(
    param1: String,
    param2: String,
    param3: String
)
```