# Is there a way to format the initializer so the arguments are automatically lined up one per line in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, coding-style

Does anyone know a way to format the initializer so the arguments are automatically lined up one per line in Xcode?

Would be nice to know if there is some script or keyboard shortcut/hotkey for that.

```swift
// Arguments on the same line
ClickableCard(image: "", title: "", value: "", action: { })

// Arguments one per line
ClickableCard(image: "",
              title: "",
              value: "",
              action: { })
```

Comment: From Xcode menu "Format to Multiple Lines": https://stackoverflow.com/a/77433763/3276518

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it but for this you have to install an app in your system.
App_name : Multiliner [download_multiliner_link](https://github.com/aheze/Multiliner/raw/main/Multiliner.zip)

After download

1. Go to System Preferences.
2. Extensions.
3. Xcode source editor . ( Enable multiliner )

Then go to your Xcode
1.Xcode preferences. ( click press command and comma to open Xcode preferences.)

1. Click Key Bindings.
2. Search 'Multiliner'
3. Then Click under key and set anything you like to set. ex. press '`command key`' and '`z`' and save them.

USE

- Select your full function and press `command key` and `z`.

Everything is set now.
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'm able to do this by selecting the whole constructor code and then pressing ^M (control + letter M).